# how to change ckeditor4 classses for alignment?

Tags: wysiwyg

As you know ckeditor4 has alignment buttons.
when you press on each button, it adds a default class.

rteleft for left, rteright for right, rtecenter for center and rtejustify for justify alignment.

I want to know a way to change these default css classes?
for example for left align, I want to use uk-text-left or for center align, I want uk-text-center

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Just need to add this config to custom javascript confiurations in advanced section of ckeditor profile.

```
config.justifyClasses = [ 'uk-text-left', 'uk-text-center', 'uk-text-right', 'uk-text-justify' ];
```